# Как использовать шаблоны в HTML без подгрузки картинок

Tags: html, шаблоны

Есть шаблон

```
<script type="text/template" id="template">
    <img src="{{icon}}">
</script>
```

Когда страница грузится, браузер пытается загрузить картинку `{{icon}}`. Как сделать так, чтобы код для шаблона не парсился?

Хотелось бы чтобы решение работало минимум в ie9.

Comment: Можно использовать другое имя атрибута. Например `<img data-src="{{icon}}">`.

Comment: @MAXOPKA тогда придется через js добавлять атрибут src